# A question in verifying conditions of Zorn' s Lemma

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, injective-module

I am studying algebra from Thomas Hunger Ford and I have a question in a thoerem on page $194-195$ of Chapter Modules.

I am adding it's image.

[image]

Edit :Question : How can I prove that every chain has a maximal element? ( For this I need to find 1 element and prove it maximal).

Any clue would be really appreciated.

Comment: The existence of a maximal element in $\mathcal S$ is *exactly* what Zorn's lemma claims

Comment: @Hagen von Eitzen I have edited the "question"  . Kindly have a look at it!!

Comment: You don't have to prove that every chain has a maximal element. That is almost surely false. You just have to prove that every chain has an **upper bound**.  If every chain in $S$ has an upper bound, then Zorn's lemma tells you that $S$ has a maximal element.

Comment: @bof ya !! But how can I prove that every chain has an upper bound?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given a chain $\{h_i\}_{i\in I}$ define a function $h$ like this:

$1.$ Define Dom$(h)=\cup_{i\in I}$ Dom$(h_i)$.

$2.$ For every $x\in $Dom$(h)$ there is some $i\in I$ such that $x\in $Dom$(h_i)$. Then define $h(x)=h_i(x)$.

Now there are a few things that you need to check: that $h$ is well defined (what if there are two distinct $i,j\in I$ such that $x\in $Dom$(h_i)\cap $Dom$(h_j)$? You need to show that in that case $h_i(x)=h_j(x)$), that it is an element of $S$ and that it is an upper bound of the chain. All of the above should be easy to check, so I'll leave it to you. Of course you have to use the fact that $\{h_i\}_{i\in I}$ is a chain and not just some random subset of $S$.

Comment: Unfortunately, I am not able to prove h is well defined. Can you please give an proof of that fact?

Comment: @Tim Assume $x\in$ Dom$(h_i)\cap$ Dom$(h_j)$. Since we are working in a chain the functions $h_i, h_j$ are comparable. This means either $h_i$ is an extension of $h_j$ or vice versa. Without loss of generality assume $h_j$ extends $h_i$. This means Dom$(h_i)\subseteq $Dom$(h_j)$ and $h_i(y)=h_j(y)$ for all $y\in$ Dom$(h_i)$. In particular $h_i(x)=h_j(x)$.

Comment: You have answered some of my questions and I am really thankful to you for that. Can you please consider answering this question also if you have some spare time https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3836031/question-in-paragraph-after-theorem-2-2-unit-5-thomas-hungerford ? I shall be really thankful!