# A question in maximal element in an ordering in which I am confused.

Tags: order-theory

This is an example on page $14$ of Algebra by Thomas Hungerford.

> $0, 3,4,5,6,...,-1, -2, -3..., 1,2.$

> $2$ is a maximal element in this ordering.

Definition of maximal element:
If ($A$, $\leq$) is a poset. An element $a\in A$ is maximal in $A$ if for every $c \in  A$ which is comparable to $a$ , $c\leq a$.

So, How is $2$ maximal in this ordering as $3,4$ are greater than $2$ ?

Can anyone please explain?

Edit:
[image]

Comment: I guess this example doesn't use the usual ordering on integers. The ordering is already given in the example, I suspect. In this example $0\leq 3 \leq 4 \leq 5 \leq 6 \leq ... \leq -1 \leq -2 \leq -3 \leq ... \leq 1 \leq2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ordering in this example is not the usual order on $\mathbb{Z}$. The author defined a completely different order. Let's call it $<^*$.

$(1)$ $0$ is the first element.

$(2)$ The next elements are the elements of $\{n\in\mathbb{N}: n\ge 3\}$, they are ordered in the usual $<$ ordering.

$(3)$ The next elements are the negative integers, ordered by the rule $n<^*m$ iff $|n|<|m|$.

$(4)$ Finally, $1$ and $2$ are the last elements with $1<^*2$.

Comment: but still how 2 is maximal element? I am sorry but I am not getting it. I am adding image of text in hope it will help in case any confusion is there!!

Comment: So in this specific order $2$ is indeed the last element. According to the order $<^*$ I described $2$ is larger than all other integers. (of course $2$ is not maximal in the usual $<$ order, but it doesn't matter, we work with a different order here)

Comment: @Tim: If you sort your classmates by height, and then move the second-shortest person to the top, they are the maximum of your order. Even if they are not the tallest person in the room.

Comment: @Mark This question was also asked by me and unfortunately no one is answering. Can you please have a look at it if you've some spare time. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3807988/a-question-in-verifying-conditions-of-zorn-s-lemma

Answer (score 1):

He **defines** an order on $\Bbb Z$ such that $2$ is the maximal element, simply by naming it last and having nothing following it. The elements on the $\ldots$ can be filled in by the reader, e.g. it's clear that in this new order $0$ is the smallest , followed directly by $3$ and then all other positive integers $\ge 4$ in order, but *any* negative number is larger then all of them, but among the negative numbers $-1$ is smallest, then $-2$ etc. (in order of absolute value). $1 < 2$ are mentioned as last and so are the largest. It's just an *informal* way of defining a well-order of type $\omega+ \omega+2$ (if you do set set theory you'll learn about ordinal numbers..).