# Question in paragraph after theorem 2.2 Unit -5 (Thomas Hungerford)

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory

I am self studying Galois Theory from Algebra by Thomas Hungerford and I have a question about the behavior of elements in $Aut_{K} F$ .

Its image:[image]

> Question is about the paragraph after proof of Theorem 2.2

> How is any $\sigma \in Aut_{K}K(u)$ determined by its action on $u$?

It's clear that {$1, u,...,u^{n-1}$ } will be basis of K(u) but why we are acting on it by $ \sigma$ ?

Also, it is clear by 2.2 that $\sigma(u) $ is a root of f by Theorem 2.2 but how does it imples $|Aut_{K} K(u) |\leq m $ ?

Actually I have been self studying and Hungerford doesn't add any justification for this, that's why problem is occurring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A general element of $K(u)$ has the form $c_0+c_1u+...+c_{n-1}u^{n-1}$ where $c_0,c_1,...,c_{n-1}\in K$, this is because $\{1,u,...,u^{n-1}\}$ is a basis. Then for $\sigma\in Aut_K K(u)$ we have:

$\sigma(\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} c_iu^i)=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\sigma(c_iu^i)=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\sigma(c_i)(\sigma(u))^i=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}c_i(\sigma(u))^i$

We just used the properties of a homomorphism and the fact that $\sigma$ sends every element of $K$ to itself. So if we know the value of $\sigma(u)$ then we know what is $\sigma(x)$ for all $x\in K(u)$.

It also follows from here that $|Aut_KK(u)|\leq m$. Let $P$ be the set of roots of $f$. We can define a function $\varphi:Aut_KK(u)\to P$ by $\varphi(\sigma)=\sigma(u)$. Since every element $\sigma\in Aut_KK(u)$ is uniquely determined by $\sigma(u)$ it follows that $\varphi$ is injective. Hence $|Aut_KK(u)|\leq |P|=m$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!!